# Vertical scrollbar not appearing

Tags: css, scrollbars

Having a problem with a vertical scrollbar. this is my html code:

```
html{
    overflow-y:visible;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

I have also tried it with 'auto', 'scroll' and just using overflow (and not specifying axis). Same results. Now I have almost identical pages that display scrollbars. the page is simple php, so that the owner can add .txt files to them (on both examples, the text on the page is a .txt file that he uploaded).

here is the example that has no scrollbar:
http://loosepartscomic.com/blazek/behindScenes.php

Here is an example where the scrollbar appears:
http://loosepartscomic.com/blazek/davesBrain.php

They both have the same divs, just different info popped in. I am at my wits end. Any of you have any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: Line 242 of scenes.css you have a media query that has `html { overflow: hidden; }`

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML class `js backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations` has `overflow: hidden` attribute. Can be found by using code inspectors on browsers.

`@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) html {`
    `overflow: hidden; }` - scenes.css line 243.